# SQL join by 2 values, one of them can be null

Tags: sql, join, null

I have 2 tables

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| itemid     | version   | anything  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| foo        | v0        |  blah     |
| foo        | v1        |  blah     |
| foo        | NULL      |  blah     |
| foo        | v2        |  meh      |
| bar        | v0        |  meh      |
| bar        | v1        |  24       |
| baz        | NULL      |  25       |
| qux        | NULL      |  26       |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

and

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| itemid     | version   | something |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| foo        | v0        |  weck     |
| foo        | NULL      |  wock     |
| foo        | v2        |  weck     |
| bar        | v0        |  meck     |
| bar        | v1        |  cuack    |
| baz        | NULL      |  crack    |
| qux        | NULL      |  blah     |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to join both tables by `itemid` and `version` so the result is like:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| itemid     | version   | anything  | something |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| foo        | v0        |  blah     |  weck     |
| foo        | v1        |  blah     |  NULL     |
| foo        | NULL      |  blah     |  wock     |
| foo        | v2        |  meh      |  weck     |
| bar        | v0        |  meh      |  meck     |
| bar        | v1        |  24       |  cuack    |
| baz        | NULL      |  25       |  crack    |
| qux        | NULL      |  26       |  blah     |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I'm doing

```
SELECT t1.itemid,
       t1.version,
       t1.anything,
       t2.something
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.itemid=t2itemid AND t1.version=t2.version
```

It's working with the rows that have a version value, but if the version value is `NULL` then the lines with null values are like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| itemid     | version   | anything  | something |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| foo        | NULL      |  blah     |  NULL     |
| baz        | NULL      |  25       |  NULL     |
| qux        | NULL      |  26       |  NULL     |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I've tried changing the join condition with:

```
ON t1.itemid=t2.itemid AND (t1.version=t2.version OR ((t1.version is null) AND (t2.version is null)))
```

with exactly the same result

I've tried also changing the condition with:

```
ON t1.itemid=t2.itemid AND (t1.version=t2.version OR ((isnull(t1.version,'-')) AND (isnull(t1.version,'-'))))
```

then I get error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,near 'AND' [SQL State=S0001, DB Errorcode=4145]`

How can I join the rows with same `itemid` and NULL `version`??

EDIT: maybe it's not important, but in my real query table1 and table2 are select results, and there is also a third select I skiped for the example that also contains itemid and version. So it's a join of selects.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your first version should work.  Are you sure `NULL` is `NULL` and not `"NULL"`, a string?

Comment: Have you tried coalescing the versions in your condition? You should be able to replace the nulls with something like v99999 that you'll likely never actually have, but since it's an actual value, it will work for the equality check.

Comment: `ON t1.itemid=t2itemid` you have a typo here - missing the dot. `ON t1.itemid=t2.itemid`

Comment: I've just tried `coalesce(t1.version,'999')=coalesce(t2.version,'999')` but same result

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili ys, it is a typo I made when I was writing the example, in the original code it's ok. If it were wrong I would get an error directly

Comment: Can you afford ALTER TABLE to make version NOT NULL, with some meaningful default like empty string? Then the problems goes away, without strange NULL hacks.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sql fiddle? with data setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem. It seems that the NULL fields are not always `NULL`, sometimes the `NULL` fields conatin something that is not a `NULL`, a `''` or a `' '`

I don't know what this fields exactly contain, is a not visible character. But fortunately, the version field always begins with `V`, so I placed this stateent in the version field:

```
IIF (t1.version like 'V%', t1.version, NULL)
```

This way I assure that this field contains a `NULL` value, and then everything seems to work fine.

Those values are suposed to be always NULL if not 'V%' so maybe is caused by who is introducing the lines in the db...

Answer (score 1):

In your last sample, you're using ISNULL incorrectly - try -

```
   SELECT t1.itemid,
           t1.version,
           t1.anything,
           t2.something
    FROM table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.itemid=t2itemid AND ISNULL(t1.version, '-') = ISNULL(t2.version, '-')
```

Comment: You are right I changed it, but I still can't get t1.anything and t2.something in the result for the null values